# Fixind invalid json in SQL

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I'm parsing json in redshift using `json_extract_path_text`, but this json is invalid (one of the fields contains double quote inside of the string value):

```
"somefield": "4 *\\"`)(z"
```

Is there any way to get rid of this quote and replace it with some other value (I do not really care about this particular data as it is wrong anyway, but I want to fetch some other parts of this json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong number of backslashes in the string.  You need either or 1, to just get the double quotes, or 3 to get a backslash and the double quote.  But this isn't really the question.

You can use the REPLACE() function to strip the \" text out.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html

```
REPLACE(json_text, '\\"', '')
```

I believe REPLACE() doesn't do any string interpretation so no additional escaping will be needed.